# When inserting a result of a query, how do I insert random exact numbers?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, create-table

I can use IDENTITY to generate unique ID numbers, but is there a way to generate a completely random number when inserting data? Currently, all ID's start with "1000"

Here is my original table:

```
CREATE TABLE Badges
(ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1000000000,23),
EmpID INTEGER NOT NULL,
EmpName nvarchar(50) not null,
EmpLastName nvarchar(50) not null,
IssueDate date default getdate(),
Validity char(1) default 'Y',
CONSTRAINT STATUS_CHECK check (Validity in ('Y','N')))
```

Below is my attempt to set up random ID number generation. I also tried to nest RAND into IDENTITY, but it did not work. Probably incorrect syntax, not so sure.

```
CREATE TABLE Badges
(Badge_ID INTEGER DEFAULT ROUND(RAND()*100000000,0) UNIQUE,
EmpID INTEGER NOT NULL,
EmpName nvarchar(50) not null,
EmpLastName nvarchar(50) not null,
IssueDate date default getdate(),
Validity char(1) default 'Y',
CONSTRAINT ID_status CHECK(Validity in ('Y','N')));
```

For a test, I tried inserting all employees from department 8 but now it generates the same Badge_ID number for everybody, at least if I insert employees in bulk and not one by one.

```
INSERT INTO Badges (EmpID, EmpName, EmpLastName)
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName FROM HR.Employee WHERE DepartmentID = 8
```

Comment: There's no way to guarantee random ***and*** unique. Besides, surrogate keys like this are intended to be for unique identification of rows ***only***. Using them for anything else is mis-use. So, exactly ***why*** are you trying to do this? What is your *functional* requirement? https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Are you just trying to replicate GUIDs? If so, just use GUIDs...`badge_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID() PRIMARY KEY` Even if so, be aware of and read up on index fragmentation.

Comment: Well, I thought about it. Like, the insert would probably fail on rare occasions when the generated number matches the existing one. That's another problem to think about.
As for why I am doing it, honestly, I do it only to learn SQL. Trying to solve any problem that comes to my mind. No SQL at my current job unfortunately so I have to think of my own problems to solve.

Comment: First time I hear about GUIDs. What is that?

Comment: The answer is to use NEWID() in your calculation of a random number, as it will return a different value on every row. As you have discovered most expressions are ***not*** recalculated on each row, which is why RAND() only works the way you want on single row inserts. However, as I pointed out, this is not something you should do, nothing exists to make it easy ***because*** it's a bad idea. Move on to your next SQL thought and keep toying with the language :)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: There are websites of SQL problems to solve which might be closer to real world situations.

Comment: `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` is often a better source of random ints

Comment: If you end up using a random number I would advise you to find a better option as your clustered index.